# GitHub Dockerfile not found at ./Dockerfile (.NET Core)

Tags: docker, github, dockerhub

I know there is some information regarding this around the web, but I am new to this technology, and the information didn't seem to help my issue.

I am trying to trigger a docker build which is connected to my GitHub repository.

When I checked the solution into master from Visual Studio, I triggered the docker build and it failed with the below.

[image]

However, a potential issue could be that the Dockerfile is present in Github but not in the root folder. The file is found when I go into the solution folder which is how Visual Studio added the file.

This is where the Dockerfile is one level down.

[image]

And it's in here.

[image]

And I do have the Dockerfile present in the solution which I published as an Image to Docker Hub.

[image]

Anything obvious I have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, DockerHub looks for a `Dockerfile` at the root of your project.

Because it is not the case here, you should specify the path to your `Dockerfile` in the [*Build rules* section](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#set-up-build-rules) :

> Specify the Dockerfile location as a path relative to the root of the source code repository. (If the Dockerfile is at the repository root, leave this path set to /.)

This screenshot shows some configuration (there are multiple build rules here, but focus on the column *Dockerfile location*) :

[image: Build rules]

In your example, you should set *Dockerfile location* to `MyFirstContainerApp/Dockerfile`.